# swift error multiple inheritance from classes NSObject and NSCoder

Tags: swift

I have a class called Diary which implements NScoder and has a member which is an array of another class called DiaryEntry

Here is my Diary class

```
import Foundation

class Diary: NSObject,NSCoder
{
    var dia=[DiaryEntry]()
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    func setDiary(ent:DiaryEntry)
    {
        if(dia.count==0)
        {
            self.dia.append(ent)

        }
        else {
            for entrie in dia
            {
                if(entrie==ent)

                {
                    entrie.text+="\n"
                    entrie.text+=ent.text
                    break
                }
                else {
                    self.dia.append(ent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.dia = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("dia") as [DiaryEntry]

        super.init() 
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
        encoder.encodeObject(dia, forKey: "dia")
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this problem because I was mistakenly using `NSCoder` instead of `NSCoding`. In using the `NSCoding` protocol, you would be correct by inheriting from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift does **not** support multiple inheritance. `NSCoder` already inherits `NSObject` so there is no reason for your `diary` class to try and inherit both (which, again, is not possible).

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy mistake to make; you accidentally used NSCoder instead of NSCoding. **-er vs -ing**

For an explanation;
NSCoder is a class, while NSCoding is a protocol. Placing another class after NSObject makes the compiler think you're asking for multiple class inheritance. Swift doesn't currently (as of 5.x) support multiple inheritance.

In Swift, you 'conform' to protocols, therefore bypassing the multiple v-table issue (and all the complexity and problems it causes) by basically merging (gross simplification) the protocol with the conforming class. You can therefore conform to as many protocols as you like (within compiler imposed limitations of course).

Long story short, you want your class to inherit from NSObject and conform to NSCoding, which is a protocol, and not inherit from both NSObject and NSCoder (which is what you were accidentally telling the compiler to do).

Answer (score 0):

the protocol's name is: NSCoding no NSCoder